# i need a little help on foreach

Tags: php

This is my cats in mysql

```
cats_id   cats_position   cats_parentid 

1            1>                0
2            1>2>              1
3            3>                0
4            1>2>4>            2
```

and i am trying to create a navigation like:

index > cars > fiat > punto

from

```
cat=4&parent=2&position=1>2>4>
```

I end up getting:

Index carcarcarcar

and my php knowledge is not enough to finish this code. can you help me please.

```
<?php
$position = trim($_GET['position']);
$pieces = explode(">", $position);

$i=0;
 foreach($pieces as $piece){
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cats
 WHERE cats_id='".$pieces[$i]."'");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 $piecesid[$i] = $row['cats_id'];
 $piecesname[$i] = $row['cats_name'];
 $piecesposition[$i] = $row['cats_position'];
 }
 $i++;
 }
 ?>
 <a href="index.php">Index</a>
 <?php $i=0; foreach($pieces as $piece){
 if($i=0)
  $parent=0;
 else
  $parent=$placesid[$i-1];
 echo '<a href="cats.php?cat='.$piecesid[$i].'&parent='.$parent.'&position='.$piecesposition[$i].'">'.$piecesname[$i];
}
```

Comment: You are missing a } right at the end after your final echo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what he is looking for:

1. Create a mysql table with id, parent_id, and name fields.
2. When a category is a "child" of another, that others parent_id field should be set accordingly, I see you already have something to that effect.
3. Use this code, setting $cat via $_GET['cat'] or something.

<?php

```
$cat = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cat']);
$res = mysql_query("select id,name,parent_id from categories where id = '$cat'");
$breadcrumb = array();
while ($category = mysql_fetch_object($res) {
    $breadcrumb[] = "<a href=\"?cat={$category->id}\">" . $category->name . "</a>"; 
    if ($category->parent_id != 0) {
        $res = mysql_query("select id,name,parent_id from categories where id = '{$category->parent_id}'");
    }
}
echo join(" > ", array_reverse($breadcrumb));
```

?>

Answer (score 4):

Your first error is a missing semicolon here:

```
$i++;
```

The second bug is a missing dot after `$parent` in the echo line:

```
     '&parent='.$parent.'&position='
```

The third (unexpected end) error will become apparent when you started to *indent your code* correctly. It's also bad style to omit the curly braces, because that makes it more difficult to find precisely such errors.

And lastly: when posting on Stackoverflow, include the **full** error message (which always mentions the line number!)

Comment: Thanks for your help. i updated the question. now i am not getting any error but i do not get the output i would like to get.

Comment: Likely a problem with your query or database contents. To reduce more complexity and add some security use: `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cats  WHERE cats_id=".intval($piece));`. The `$i` counter is redundant since you already use a `foreach`. If you have an error, then `print mysql_error();` should tell you about it. And do a `print_r($piecesid);` to see if anything was collected.

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed your foreach in the last php section

```
 <?php $i=0; foreach($pieces as $piece){
 if($i=0)
  $parent=0;
 else
  $parent=$placesid[$i-1];
 echo '<a href="cats.php?cat='.$piecesid[$i].'&parent='.$parent'&position='.$piecesposition[$i].'>'.$piecesname[$i];
  //Missing } here
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you're missing a **}** at the end. Just put a } after the last line like this:

```
echo '<a href="cats.php?cat='.$piecesid[$i].'&parent='.$parent'&position='.$piecesposition[$i].'>'.$piecesname[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you don't need cats_position in your table. 
To handle hierarchical data like this you can use a nested set (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) or just rely on the parent_id.
The advantage of this is, that you for example don't need multiple parameters in your get query. Instead of

```
cat=4&parent=2&position=1>2>4>
```

you then archieve the same with:

```
cat=4
```